# jQuery - Can't get ajax request to work in IE, no useful error messages given

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem performing a simple .getJSON request in Internet Explorer (both variations of the code below work in all other browsers). Specifically with the piece below - I am able to perform .getJSON requests successfully in other sections of my code but for some reason the piece below refuses to cooperate.

```
var dateFormatted = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY");  
var get_dates_url = window.location.href + "/available_dates?start="+dateFormatted._d+"&end="+dateFormatted._d+"&_="+(new Date().getTime());

console.log(get_dates_url);

$.getJSON(get_dates_url, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  $("#appendList").html("Select a timeslot you'd like to schedule");

        var available_times = JSON.stringify(availableTimes(result));
        var service_length = $("#serviceMinutes").text();

        var get_times_url = window.location.href + "/available_times?available_times="+available_times+"&service_length="+service_length+"&_="+Math.random();
        console.log(get_times_url);

        $.ajax({
          url: get_times_url,
          cache: false,
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "JSON",
          method: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function() {
              var parseTime = moment.parseZone(this.time);
              var availableTime = parseTime.format('hh:mm a');
              $("#appendList").append("<li class='timeslot' data-time='" + this.time + "' data-formatted_time='" + availableTime + "'>" + availableTime  + " <button class='scheduler-button green-btn'>Select</button></li>");
            });
            selectDateButton();
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
});
```

The resulting console.log(get_dates_url); looks like this:

> "http://localhost:3000/professionals/29/available_dates?start=2015-11-05T00:00:00.000Z&end=2015-11-05T00:00:00.000Z&_=1446741826656"

I've tried preventing any sort of cache issues as per other recommendations with the addition of JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime()); at the end of my URL.

I've also added jQuery.support.cors = true; to my code in case it's a cross-origin issue.

I've also modified the original .getJSON code to be an ajax request to look like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: get_dates_url,
      cache: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        var available_times = JSON.stringify(availableTimes(result));
        var service_length = $("#serviceMinutes").text();

        var get_times_url = window.location.href + "/available_times?available_times="+available_times+"&service_length="+service_length+"&_="+Math.random();

        console.log(get_times_url);

        $.ajax({
          url: get_times_url,
          cache: false,
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "JSON",
          method: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function() {
              var parseTime = moment.parseZone(this.time);
              var availableTime = parseTime.format('hh:mm a');
              $("#appendList").append("<li class='timeslot' data-time='" + this.time + "' data-formatted_time='" + availableTime + "'>" + availableTime  + " <button class='scheduler-button green-btn'>Select</button></li>");
            });
            selectDateButton();
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
    });
```

All I'm getting back from IE is an error message that says "Error" and no visible errors in the console. Any ideas what can be causing this issue?

EDIT:

I've also tried adding "&callback=?" to the end of my URL's as well.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and what version of IE are you using?

Comment: @tabz100 Same issue on IE9 and above, haven't tested IE8. Running jQuery 1.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I hope this helps anyone who encounters the same issue but it turns out IE specifically doesn't like the way I was constructing the URL by passing in the data that way. Instead, pass the data via the ajax data attributes:

```
var dataToSend = { 'start' : dateFormatted._d, 'end' : dateFormatted._d };

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.href + "/available_dates",
    cache: false,
    data: dataToSend,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
    }
});
```

I also added $.support.cors = true; to my javascript file.

I'm not entirely sure which of these corrected my issue.